# Getting allready created component model instance in a module (singleton)

Tags: module, mvc, model

I have a module, that does some stuff and needs the data from the list model of my component. Everything is coded in MVC pattern using the Joomla framework.

When clicking on a menu item the list model is outputting data to the view and displaying it. Just like an list of article items.

Now i need that data in the module, but when writing something like this:

```
$objects = BaseDatabaseModel::getInstance('Objects', 'MyModel', array('ignore_request' => true));
$data = $objects->getItems();
```

There is a new model instance created. Now my model does a lot performance heavy stuff and i need exactly the data that is allready created once and used in the listing output. Why create another instance and trigger the same query twice? I my case always creating a model object is not wanted.

There is a nice article about the subject here, but no solution for getting a singleton instance is provided:
https://magazine.joomla.org/all-issues/july-2014/why-the-poor-old-singleton-was-banned

Is there a singleton way to get the data of internal memory based cache Joomla Model is creating in another place like a module?